# 'ArticleSerializer' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, serialization, active-model-serializers

The article serializer:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Article
        fields='__all__'
```

settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField()
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

view function:

```
def article_list(request):
    if request.method== 'GET':
        article =Article.objects.all()
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(article,many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data,safe=False)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser.parse(request)
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data,status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors,status=400)
```

i just created a  simple serializer but whenever i try to get the response it says that the ArticleSerializer i created has no attribute 'get'.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3bRi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `request.data` to the serializer. You are parsing the whole request object and passing that instead of the required data.

```
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=request.data)
```